# extract data from all .cif files in folder and write to a line in new file (.txt or .csv)

Tags: python

**UPDATE:**

As per request in comments I have updated the post to clarify that the input cif files can vary in their layout and to share the Traceback error I receive.

I also want to thank those that have provided feedback and help here so far, especially @CodeMonkey - cheers!

```
#######################################################################
#
#                 Cambridge Crystallographic Data Centre
#                                CCDC 
#
#######################################################################
#
# If this CIF has been generated from an entry in the Cambridge 
# Structural Database, then it will include bibliographic, chemical, 
# crystal, experimental, refinement or atomic coordinate data resulting 
# from the CCDC's data processing and validation procedures.
#
#######################################################################

data_PYRAZI
_symmetry_cell_setting           orthorhombic
_symmetry_space_group_name_H-M   'P m n n'
_symmetry_Int_Tables_number      58
_space_group_name_Hall           '-P 2n 2'
loop_
_symmetry_equiv_pos_site_id
_symmetry_equiv_pos_as_xyz
1 x,y,z
2 1/2-x,1/2-y,1/2+z
3 x,-y,-z
4 1/2-x,1/2+y,1/2-z
5 -x,-y,-z
6 1/2+x,1/2+y,1/2-z
7 -x,y,z
8 1/2+x,1/2-y,1/2+z
_cell_length_a                   9.316(3)
_cell_length_b                   3.815(5)
_cell_length_c                   5.911(3)
_cell_angle_alpha                90
_cell_angle_beta                 90
_cell_angle_gamma                90
_cell_volume                     210.08
loop_
_atom_site_label
_atom_site_type_symbol
_atom_site_fract_x
_atom_site_fract_y
_atom_site_fract_z
N1 N 0.14850 0.00000 0.00000
C1 C 0.07280 0.11130 0.17330
H1 H 0.13000 0.19200 0.31700
C1B C 0.07280 -0.11130 -0.17330
C1F C -0.07280 0.11130 0.17330
C1D C -0.07280 -0.11130 -0.17330
H1B H 0.13000 -0.19200 -0.31700
N1D N -0.14850 0.00000 0.00000
H1F H -0.13000 0.19200 0.31700
H1D H -0.13000 -0.19200 -0.31700

#END
```

Script currently being used:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path
import csv

writer = None
with open("out.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    for f in Path('.').glob("*.cif"):
        print(f)
        with open(f, "r") as fin:
            row = {}
            for line in fin:
                line = line.strip()
                if len(line) == 0 or line.startswith("#"):
                    # skip blank lines and comments
                    continue
                # this matches lines like "_cell_length_a   9.316(3)"
                # and splits the input into 2 variables.
                # also ignore lines like "_symmetry_equiv_pos_site_id"
                if m := re.match(r"_?(\w+)\s+(.*)", line):
                    key = m.group(1)
                    value = m.group(2)
                    if key.startswith("cell_length") or key.startswith("cell_angle"):
                        if m := re.match(r"([^)]+)\(([^)]+)\)", value):
                            # split off the uncertainty
                            value = m.group(1)
                            unc = m.group(2)
                            # add uncertainty as separate column
                            row[key + "_unc"] = unc
                            row["filename"] = f 
                        row[key] = value
            
            print(row)
            if writer is None:
                # this is the first row found
                # create the .csv file with column names
                # from the keys in the .cif file (e.g. _cell_length_a)
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=sorted(row.keys()))
                writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The .cif files that I will be using will vary in their layout i.e. some will have more lines than other and the desired fields will be on different line numbers etc but they will always be labelled in exactly the same way e.g., "_cell_length_a"

The error I encounter is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\CSD_API\unit_cell.py", line 39, in <module>
    writer.writerow(row)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\csv.py", line 154, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\csv.py", line 149, in _dict_to_list
    raise ValueError("dict contains fields not in fieldnames: "
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'cell_angle_alpha_unc', 'cell_angle_gamma_unc'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Path('.').glob("*.cif")` will iterate all the .cif files in the specified path.

Next, when iterating over the .cif file contents, you can use `re.match(r"(\w+)\s+(.*)", line)` expression to match the lines with a key identifier and a value; e.g. `_cell_length_a   9.316(3)`.

If want to strip the "_" prefix in the names so "_cell_length_a" becomes "cell_length_a" then add _? to the regexp.

Can try something like this to iterate over all the .cif files in a given directory and add each as a new line in .CSV output file.

```python
import re
from pathlib import Path
import csv

# these are for fields that may contain uncertainties in some but not all of the input files
# additional fields should be added to this list
additional_fields = ["cell_angle_alpha_unc", "cell_angle_beta",
                     "cell_angle_gamma_unc"]

keys = writer = None
with open("out.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    for f in Path('.').glob("*.cif"):
        with open(f, "r") as fin:
            row = {}
            for line in fin:
                line = line.strip()
                if len(line) == 0 or line.startswith("#"):
                    # skip blank lines and comments
                    continue
                # this matches lines like "_cell_length_a   9.316(3)"
                # and splits the input into 2 variables.
                # also ignore lines like "_symmetry_equiv_pos_site_id"
                if m := re.match(r"_?(\w+)\s+(.*)", line):
                    key = m.group(1)
                    value = m.group(2)
                    if key.startswith("cell_length") or key.startswith("cell_angle"):
                        if m := re.match(r"([^)]+)\(([^)]+)\)", value):
                            # split off the uncertainty
                            value = m.group(1)
                            unc = m.group(2)
                            # add uncertainty as separate column
                            name = key + "_unc"
                            if keys is not None and name not in keys:
                                print("WARN: unknown key:", key)
                            else:
                                row[name] = unc
                        if keys is not None and key not in keys:
                            print("WARN: unknown key:", key)
                        else:
                            row[key] = value
            print(row)
            if writer is None:
                # this is the first row found
                # create the .csv file with column names
                # from the keys in the .cif file (e.g. _cell_length_a)
                keys = set(row.keys())
                # add in additional fields just in case missing in first file
                for key in additional_fields:
                    keys.add(key)
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=sorted(keys))
                writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(row)
```

With the example .cif file the csv output would be:

```
cell_angle_alpha,cell_angle_alpha_unc,cell_angle_beta,cell_angle_gamma,cell_angle_gamma_unc,cell_length_a,cell_length_a_unc,cell_length_b,cell_length_b_unc,cell_length_c,cell_length_c_unc
90,,90,90,,9.316,3,3.815,5,5.911,3
80,1,80,80,2,1.316,3,2.815,5,3.911,3
```

**UPDATE:**

The code above was updated to reflect case where the values in some files have uncertainity values in ()'s and others don't. Will output a WARNING if finds a field name in a subsequent file that is not in the first file. If see more fields then add them to `additional_fields` list variable.

Comment: Many thanks for this, a nice neat way to do it.  Ive never used this way to write out the values before, but would there be a neat way to allow the input file name to be written to each line too?  I ask this as I will be running the script to go through many .cif files and I will need to match up the output to specific input files for later analysis.  Also, the uncertainty of the values (shown in parentheses), is it possible to easily seperate these in the output?

Comment: @matsmcfly.  You can add a check to the value if it contains an uncertainty; e.g. `re.match(r"(.*?)\(\d+\)")` then split it into the raw value and the uncertainty value. See updated answer.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for me, the updated script seems to write out values of all of the fields, not just the lengths+angles.  It works as intended if I change the indentation of the `row[key] = value` line, but in both cases this now seems to only pull values from one file rather than all in directory

Comment: @matsmcfly Add a line to print each filename and make sure the `writer.writerow(row)` is properly indented at same level as `print(row)`.

Comment: I still cant get this working, the script seems to fail with an error relating to the dictionary.    I received some feedback to use a format like the following: `headers = ["filename", ... ] # any other required fields can go in here. 
rows = []
...
    # when you generate a header key
    if key not in headers:
        headers.append(key)
    row[key] = ...
    ...
    # after completing a row
    rows.append(row)
    
# After processing
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers)
writer.writeheader()
for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(row)`  How to  implement this?

Comment: @matsmcfly Update your question with your current code and full error stack trace including what line error is on. Also, do all your CIF files have all the same fields or can some have more or less fields -- that could lead to an error since the header is being defined by the first file.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got access to the CSD Python API you could use the `io.EntryReader` class [[Docs]](https://downloads.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/documentation/API/descriptive_docs/io.html) to open the CIF file. That will parse all the cif attributes and make them accessible via a dictionary. From there you can save, print, transform, and do whatever else.

For the above example:

```py
from ccdc.io import EntryReader
import glob
import os

desired_path = "."
cifs = glob.glob(os.path.join(desired_path,"*.cif"))

for file in cifs:
    cif = EntryReader(file)[0]
    print(cif.attributes.keys())
```

Output :

```
['_atom_site_fract_x', '_atom_site_fract_y', '_atom_site_fract_z', '_atom_site_label', '_atom_site_type_symbol', '_cell_angle_alpha', '_cell_angle_beta', '_cell_angle_gamma', '_cell_length_a', '_cell_length_b', '_cell_length_c', '_cell_volume', '_space_group_name_Hall', '_symmetry_Int_Tables_number', '_symmetry_cell_setting', '_symmetry_equiv_pos_as_xyz', '_symmetry_equiv_pos_site_id', '_symmetry_space_group_name_H-M']
```

Now you can send it to pandas or use your own csv writer or do whatever else your heart desires :)